# Canvas image ignoring cache-control, in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching, canvas

I have a web page that is loading an image into a canvas element, where the URL of the image points to a web service.  On the webservice, we're setting the image's response headers to private, no-cache and maxAge(0).

Our problem is that the image can be changed on the server.  When we open the page after the image has been changed, in IE11, we get the new image. It appears that in IE, the canvas element is abiding by the cache-control settings, and is downloading the image again.

When we open the page after the image has been changed in Chrome, we get the old image, until we do a page refresh.

How can we make Chrome abide by the cache-control headers?